# Writing a Loop to Pull Account Data from Oanda API with 100 query limit [R]

Tags: r, api, loops, trading, forex

I have the below function 'AccountHisTransactions' in which this pulls historical transactions from my trading account. The challenge that I am having is that I want to pull all of the data available in the account so I can analyze the data and build a application to review trades. The current function allow allows 100 rows of data when I call it. When I place an integer in 'pag' object it will pull that page specifically from the API. I have tried various things but the json documentation states I can only enter an integer here. Instead of running this function multiple times to pull all the data, is there a way that someone can assist me with understanding how to construct a loop or some method to pull all of the data into R rather than 100 increments?

Thank you in advance for your help

```
AccountHistTransactions  <- function(AccountType,AccountID,Token,Instrument,Count,ApiVersion) {

if(AccountType == "practice"){
httpaccount <- "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com"
} else if (AccountType == "live"){
httpaccount <- "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com"
} else {
print("Account type error. Must be practice or live")
}  
if(missing(ApiVersion) || ApiVersion == "v1") {

ApiVersion <- "v1"

# -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version 1.0 -- #
# -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

auth      <- c(Authorization = paste("Bearer",Token,sep=" "))
Queryhttp <- paste(httpaccount,"/v1/accounts/",sep="")
Querythttp1 <- paste(Queryhttp,AccountID,sep="")
Querythttp2 <- paste(Querythttp1,"/transactions?instrument=",sep="")
Querythttp3 <- paste(Querythttp2,Instrument,sep="")
Querythttp4 <- paste(Querythttp3,"&count=",sep="")
Querythttp5 <- paste(Querythttp4,Count,sep="")
QueryInst1  <- getURL(Querythttp5,cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem",
                                                     package="RCurl"),httpheader=auth)
InstJson <- fromJSON(QueryInst1, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

return(InstJson)

# -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version 2.0 -- #
# -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

} else if (ApiVersion == "v2") {

auth      <- c(Authorization = paste("Bearer",Token,sep=" "))
Queryhttp <- paste(httpaccount,"/v3/accounts/",sep="")
Querythttp1 <- paste(Queryhttp,AccountID,sep="")
Querythttp2 <- paste(Querythttp1,"/transactions?instrument=",sep="")
Querythttp3 <- paste(Querythttp2,Instrument,sep="")
Querythttp4 <- paste(Querythttp3,"&count=",sep="")
Querythttp5 <- paste(Querythttp4,Count,sep="")
QueryInst1  <- getURL(Querythttp5,cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem",
                                                     package="RCurl"),httpheader=auth)
InstJson <- fromJSON(QueryInst1, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

pagesize <- InstJson$pageSize
count    <- InstJson$count
Hist <- data.frame()

curlOptions(filter = "")
pag <- paste0(InstJson$pages[1])
QI1 <- getURL(pag,cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem", package="RCurl"), httpheader=auth)
IJ  <- fromJSON(QI1, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

return(IJ)
} 
    }


##TESTING CODE ABOVE-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#p1_AccountType <- "live"
#p2_Token       <- "-TOKEN"
#p3_Instrument  <- 
#p4_AccountID   <- "000-000-000000-00"
#p5_ApiVersion  <- "v2"
#p6_Count <- 3
#OA_HistTrans  <- AccountHistTransactions(AccountType = p1_AccountType,
                                      AccountID = p4_AccountID,
                                      Token = p2_Token, Instrument = p3_Instrument,
                                       Count = p6_Count, ApiVersion = p5_ApiVersion)

 ####--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------###
```

Comment: Do you have an ID of some sort that differentiates each iteration (each of your 100 increments)?

Comment: I do actually have that, if you have an easier solution to what I posted let me know! Thanks for reviewing

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as Parfait below: read up on the use of lapply (or sapply if you have variations for each iteration). Organize your ID's into a list and pass the list to lapply. Loops seem more intuitive, but the apply functions will quickly become your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curlOptions(filter = "")
#print(length(InstJson$pages))
finalVect <- c()
for( pageLink in InstJson$pages ) {
  QI1 <- getURL(pageLink,cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem", package="RCurl"), httpheader=auth)
  finalVect <- rbind(finalVect, fromJSON(QI1, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE))
}

return(finalVect)
}   
 }
```

I was able to create an empty dataframe and then loop through the results rbinding the information together

Comment: Avoid `rbind` in a loop which leads to quadratic copy. Instead, build a list of data frames and then call `rbind` **once** outside loop: `final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Can you show me the syntax to do this correctly? I attempted to write it myself but an error was produced:

Comment: Build list with `lapply`: `df_list <- lapply(InstJson$pages, function(pageLink) { ...same two lines inside for-loop })`. Then concatenate all dfs into one: `final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!